# Node Js Express Static File fails when URL get

Tags: node.js, json

I am new to Node Js and doing some practice examples. Static files doesn't serve properly when sending get request as url id.

```
    app.use(express.static('public'));

    // It works. Static files loaded properly from http://localhost:3000/themify-icons.css
    app.get('/about', (req,res) => {
        res.render('about', {
            title: 'About'
        });
    });

    // It opens productdetail.ejs but Static files failed here. 
// When I check the 'css' from view page source, Its locating to http://localhost:3000/product/themify-icons.css
    app.get('/product/:id',(req,res) => {
        // console.log(req.params.id);

        res.render('productdetail', {
            title:'Product Details'
        });
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

`app('/product/:id')` opens productdetail.ejs but Static files failed here. When I check the 'css' from view page source, Its locating to `http://localhost:3000/product/themify-icons.css`.

I understand its adding 'product' in the path. How do I resolve this even in this url id get method also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser is requesting `http://localhost:3000/product/themify-icons.css`, but you want it to just request `http://localhost:3000/themify-icons.css`, then change the url in the tag to have a leading `/`.  So, instead of

```
"themify-icons.css"
```

use:

```
"/themeify-icons.css"
```

In your `<style>` or `<link>` tag.  This should be true for all static resources that you don't want the path from the page URL to be added to.

When you have only a filename, the browser takes the path from the page URL and adds that to the filename.  When you have a leading `/`, then the browser just takes the protocol, host and port from the page URL, not the path.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'public' folder is directly in the project root, write

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

instead of

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

to get the correct path relative from the project root. 
`__dirname` will refer to the folder in wich your current script is executed.

---

**Note**: you need to require the "path" module:

```
let path = require('path');
```

Comment: Not working.
`/home/user/Node/sproject/views/productdetail.ejs
/home/user/Node/sproject/views/about.ejs
/home/user/Node/sproject/public/css/main.css`
Everything on sproject folder.